# Can Salesforce Accept Push API notifications?

Tags: rest-api, api

I'm working on an API integration and part of it is to get updates on order statuses. The company that built the API would like to send push notifications to Salesforce to notify us when an order status changes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Salesforce can receive inbound notifications. However, the sender must authenticate with Salesforce using OAuth (described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm).)